# WebGL painfully slow on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, webgl

**TLDR**; WebGL running smooth Win10 & previous Ubuntu 18. Now it's really bad.

I'm running a well updated Ubuntu 20.04 on my XPS15 9550.
Since I updated from Ubuntu 18 I recognized WebGL or other graphic intense browser apps run very slow.

**Specs;**

```
Core i5-6300HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz
GeForce GTX 960M
Samsung NVMe SSD 500GB
```

[Hardware probe listing GTX960 as "detected"](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=e97e5c9f62) and not "working", Idk...

As a driver I use the proprietary `nvidia-driver-450` package.

Running `glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"` returns my GTX960M as the active graphic unit. Doing a GPU benchmark with *glmark2* returns neat results and shows;

```
=======================================================
OpenGL Information
GL_VENDOR:     NVIDIA Corporation
GL_RENDERER:   GeForce GTX 960M/PCIe/SSE2
GL_VERSION:    4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.102.04
```

Running [FishGL](http://www.fishgl.com/) gives me 2fps.

My very specific question ist; **WHY**?

Answer (score 3):

Wow. **Fixed it** super easily;

- Type chrome://flags in the address bar
- Press Ctrl + f and type ” Rendering list “, “Override
  software rendering list” should come up, enable it.
- Also check "hardware exeleration" in your chrome settings.
- Restart your browser (console; `killall chrome`)

-> Enjoy your hardware